# Working with Python Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

What is wrong with this code please:

```
from array import array
import math

def solution(A):
A = array('i')
for i in A:
    if i > 0:
        digits = int(math.log10(i))+1
    elif i == 0:
        digits = 1
    else:
        digits = int(math.log10(-i))+2
        if digits == 2:
            sum += i    
    return sum
```

The task is to write a function that given an array A consisting of N integers, returns the sum of all two digit numbers

Comment: The `return` is **in** the loop, so the `for` loop will only be executed **once**... Furthermore wouldn't you consider `9 < i < 100` be a more elegant test? It is a one liner without much corner cases. In case *negative* numbers have to be taken into account, you can also use `9 < abs(i) < 100`...

Comment: I get an error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'sum' referenced before assignment" when I remove the return statement from the for loop. The assumed range for array elements is [-2,147,483,648..2,147,483,647]

Comment: What's the error???

Comment: you never define sum, you just try to add to it. somwhere in your function body you need a `sum = 0`

Comment: The first thing that's wrong with it is the indentation in line 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job

```
import math
def solution(A):
    #A = array('i')
    sumofarr=0
    for i in A:
        if i != 0:
            digits = int(math.log10(math.fabs(i)))+1
            if digits == 2:
                sumofarr += i    
    return sumofarr
solution([12,3,45]) #output 57
```

Note that there is no need to separate between positive and negative numbers. Just take the absolute value. Also, you need to initialize the `sumofarr` variable at the beginning. Also it is better not to use `sum` as a name for variable, as this is already used as a name of function in python.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is that you don't initialize `sum`, don't have the correct indentation, overwrite the input argument and the check if a number is of 2 digit is more complicate that it need to be

here is a more simple version

```
def mysum(A):
    total = 0
    for i in A:
        if 10 <= abs(i) < 100: # abs if you want to include negative numbers
            total += i
    return total
```

test

```
>>> test = [1, 2, 10, 80, 20, -10, -20, 500]
>>> mysum(test)
80
```

or with the build-in sum and a generator expression

```
>>> sum( i for i in test if 10 <= abs(i) < 100 )
80
>>>
```